# File name string not working

Tags: python, string, filepath

In my program when I call this filename:

```
msTestPrompt = r'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\MSTest.exe"'
```

It doesnt work, it says the filename, directory name or volume syntax is incorrect. I have tried  just about every combination of ways to fix this and I just can't get it working, no matter what I do to the string. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Here is what uses the file name string

```
p = subprocess.Popen([msTestPrompt, blah], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Edit2: Here is the blah variable:

```
resultsFile = "/resultsfile:" + os.path.normpath('"C:/BB1.trx"')
testSettings = "/testsettings:" + os.path.normpath('"C:/Users/bgb/Documents/Brent/Code/Visual Studio/Local.testsettings"')
testContainer = '/testcontainer:"C:\Users\bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio\DesignF.UnitTests\bin\Debug\DesignF-UnitTests.dll"'
blah = str(' ' + testContainer + ' ' + resultsFile + ' ' + testSettings)
```

Comment: Is that the *exact* code? Note that in the first case you have a variable called `msTestPrompt` but in the other you use `msBuildPrompt`. What's the value of `msBuildPrompt`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`msTestPrompt = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe'`

If you place `r` in front of a string you don't need to escape the backslash anymore.

EDIT:
What if you change the `blah` variable to this:

```
resultsFile = r'/resultsfile:C:\BB1.trx'
testSettings = r'/testsettings:C:\Users\bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio\Local.testsettings'
testContainer = r'/testcontainer:C:\Users\bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio\DesignF.UnitTests\bin\Debug\DesignF-UnitTests.dll'
blah = str(' ' + testContainer + ' ' + resultsFile + ' ' + testSettings)
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Also post the code that uses the sTestPrompt variable

Comment: The error says: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: That code is fine. I tested it and it works. Perhaps the problem is the `blah` variable?

Comment: Well see, when I copy and paste everything into command line prompt it works, but then when I run this program it doesn't work so if this is fine, then I am truly clueless as to what is wrong... :( I'll post the blah variable here in a sec